# How to select element more efficient from list of pairs based on a list of zeros and ones in Python

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a list of pairs which looks like the following:
[(0,1),(2,3),(7,9),(10, 11)] and a list of 0s and 1s.

Suppose we want to select pairs based on lists of 0s and 1s.

For example: If we have [(0,1,0,1)], then we should select [(2,3),(10,11)]

Notice inside [], both types are tuples. (expect to get a list of tuples)

Can anyone give some suggestions to do this effectively without using for loop?

Comment: Is your list of 1s and 0s also gonna be a tuple, or can it just be a list like so: [0, 1, 0, 1]?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a for loop? If you absolutely can't use `for`, you can try `map`

Comment: I used itertools.product[0,1] to generate this list, it automatically returns tuples. I think I can do it either a tuple or [0,1,0,1]. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.compress`. There are dozens of duplicates of this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use for loop is that I'm trying to select all possible combination of this tuples. Some tuples list is really long. then the possible combination is a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still going to use a `for` loop at one level or another somewhere along the lines, but you could use `itertools.compress`, eg:

```
from itertools import compress

source = [(0,1),(2,3),(7,9),(10, 11)]
select = [(0,1,0,1)]

selected = list(compress(source, select[0]))
# [(2, 3), (10, 11)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a list comprehension for this, for example:

```
bitmap = [1, 0, 1, 0]
tup_list = [(0,1),(2,3),(7,9),(10, 11)]

result = [tup for tup, bit in zip(tup_list, bitmap) if bit == 1]
```

You can also use `itertools.compress` like Jon Clements suggested, but that is less often used and I believe a list comprehension will be more understandable for most readers.

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [(0,1), (2,3), (7,9) ,(10, 11)]
list2 = [0,1,0,1]
outputlist = []
i = 0    
while i < len(list2):
    if list2[i] == 1:
        outputlist.append(list1[i])
    i += 1
print(outputlist)
```

Answer (score -1):

Without a loop, you can use map:

```
s = [(0,1,0,1)]
s = list(s[0])

l = [(0,1),(2,3),(7,9),(10, 11)]

final_list = map(lambda x: x[-1] if x[0] == 1 else None, zip(s, l))

final_list = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, final_list))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (10, 11)]
```